# How to write over an operator?

Tags: c#, operators

```
class Test
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }

    public Test(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static int operator +(Test a)
    {
        int test = a.a*a.b;
        return test;
    }

    public void Testa()
    {
        Test t = new Test(5, 5);
        Console.WriteLine((t.a + t.b));
    }
}
```

When I call the Testa() method I want the result to be 5*5, but I'm not sure how to use this method above were I write over the + operator

Comment: Why would you overload the `+` operator to be the `*` operator? Wouldn't it make more sense to just use `*`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your code doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: It's just for a simple exercise, so I understand how to work with this

Comment: If you want to understand things, it's probably best to do them sensibly (i.e. don't overload operators with operators that do totally different things).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method overloads the *unary* `+` operator. So you can see it in action if you write:

```
Test t = new Test(5, 5);
Console.WriteLine(+t); // Prints 25
```

If you wanted to overload the *binary* `+` operator, you'd need to give two parameters. For example:

```
// I strongly suggest you don't use "a" and "b"
// as parameter names when they're already (bad) property names
public static int operator +(Test lhs, Test rhs)
{
    return lhs.a * rhs.b + lhs.b * rhs.a;    
}
```

Then use it as:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Test x = new Test(2, 3);
    Test y = new Test(4, 5);
    Console.WriteLine(x + y); // Prints 22 (2*5 + 3*4)
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity is it really overloading or just defining since if it is not defined in this particular case, you can't use it. I know it is called overloading in the literature because you usually overload operators that are already defined for some class (like == operator). Thank you in advance!

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick: It's overloading. The name "+" means different things depending on the argument types, just like when you overload methods.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick It's called overloading the operator not because it's replacing an existing overload, but in the sense of method overloading.  If there is a method `Foo(Bar b)` and you add a new method `Foo(Baz z)` you just added a new "overload" to `Foo`.  `Foo` is said to be "overloaded" because it can have different meanings depending on the context.  In the same sense, this is adding a new overload to the `+` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.  The + operator overloads for integers are a part of the C# language specs, and cannot be overridden by user code.

What you could do is the following:

```
public class Test
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }

    public Test(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static Test operator +(Test first, Test second)
    {
        return new Test(first.a * second.a
            , first.b * second.b);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return a.ToString() + " " + b.ToString();
    }

    public void Testa()
    {
        Test t = new Test(5, 5);
        Test t2 = new Test(2, 6);
        Console.WriteLine(t + t2);
    }
}
```

The idea here is that you're overloading the operator for a `Test` class, not an `int`.

In your case you were actually overloading the unary plus operator, not the binary operator.

Comment: The operator overload given by the OP is fine - he just wasn't invoking it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I looked at the result he was trying to get an did my best to emulate how to get it, rather than demonstrate how to properly use the operator he did create.  I realize that it's technically a valid unary operator.

Comment: It still isn't clear to me exactly what the OP *does* want to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed; this was simply my best guess at interpreting his intentions.